# How to handle tile request errors from ol.source.WMTS - Openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

By using the obvious event handler::

```
layer.getSource().on('tileloaderror', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
});
```

I get an output rather useless, since it **doesn't seem to contain any information regarding HTTP Response body/headers** etc.

Is there a way to access those kind of information after a failed tile request?
In my implementation, access token must be updated, **thus response code is necessary**.

If not possible after all, maybe there is a way to create a custom tile load request (maybe implement my own "*tileloadfunction*" or something).

Comment: Why API docs for older versions are removed? Can not find doc for the version I use (4.2) anywhere... That makes devel impossible,since I'm not planning on updating ol version any time soon...

Comment: You can use this link to find some previous example. But they should keep the previous example
http://tsauerwein.github.io/ol3/animation-flights/examples/